# react native: passing the value of selected items to a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to implement a `MultipleSelectList` from this library `react-native-dropdown-select-list`. And I am saving the selected items in the `AsyncStorage` of `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage`. I implemented 2 useState variables: first `const [selected, setSelected] = useState([{}]);` this is a list of `{name : muscleGroup, value : id(s) of the exercise(s)}` (this is the object that is saved in the list of viewDataList [see setExerciseViewLists ]). The other useState variable that I have implemented is:

```
const [selectedCount, setSelectedCount] = useState({  // a list of the number of selected exercises per muscleGroup
    Back: 0,
    Legs: 0,
    Chest: 0,
    .....
  });
```

The idea: when I call `handleSelect` (see handleSelect) from my `MultipleSelectList` I give it 2 parameters (val and item) val should be the id(s) of the exercise(s) because I defined it as this in my `MultipleSelectList` (see MultipleSelectList) and the item is one list item from `viewDataList`.

The problem is: val is for some reason, not an ID or a list of IDs, it is an anonymous function:

```
function (val) {
   var temp = _babel_runtime_helpers_toConsumableArray__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default()(new 
   Set([].concat(_babel_runtime_helpers_toConsumableArray__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default()(val),
   [value])));
   
   return temp;
}
```

(I don't really understand what this is). Any help would be appriciated.

**MultipleSelectList**

```
{viewDataList.map((item, index) => (
  <MultipleSelectList
    data={item.list.map(listItem => ({
      value: listItem.id,                 //here
    }))}
    save="value"
    setSelected={(val) => handleSelect(val, item)}
    selected={selected.map(item => item.value)}
  />
))}
```

**handleSelect/Async saving**

```
const handleSelect = async (val, item) => {

    setSelectedCount(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [item.name]: prevState[item.name] + 1,   //item.name = muscleGroup
    }));

    setSelected(prevState => ([
      ...prevState,
      {
        name: item.name,
        value: val                             //val should be the ID(s)
      },
    ]));

    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('selected', JSON.stringify([
        ...selected,
        {
          name: item.name,
          value: val,
        }
      ]));

      await AsyncStorage.setItem('selectedCount', JSON.stringify({
        ...selectedCount,
        [item.name]: selectedCount[item.name] + 1,
      }));

    } catch (e) {
      console.e('Error saving data to AsyncStorage:', e);
    }
};
```

**setExerciseViewLists**

```
const setExerciseViewLists = () => {
    let list = [];

    list.push(
      {.....},
      {
        num: 3,
        name: "muscleGroup",
        list: [{.....}, { id: "123", exercises : "somthing" }, {.....}]
      },
      {.....},
    );

  setViewDataList(list);
};
```

Comment: Hi @Naik, Could you give me the viewDataList value that you are passing as a prop? And I need one more clarification. Are you trying to render a List of lists? Because according to the above implementation, you would render multiple MultipleSelectLists.

Comment: The issue is simple, you are passing the data prop of MultipleSelectList as an array of anonymous functions instead of an array of objects i.e. instead of sending data={[{id: 'some id 1'}, {id: 'some id 2'}]}, you are sending it like data={[() => {}, () => {}]}. Please check it once.

Comment: @Gavara.Suneel I am setting the viewDataList value in setExerciseViewLists(). And no I should have one MultipleSelectList, but this MultipleSelectList is in a Card, so I am rendering cards with MultipleSelectList. Each card represents a muscle group and for each muscle group, there are a number of exercises that you can select from.

Comment: @Gavara.Suneel I implemented viewDataList like this: const [viewDataList, setViewDataList] = useState([]);

Comment: @Gavara.Suneel `an array of anonymous functions instead of an array of objects` yeah this is exactly my problem but I do not understand why, because I am mapping in the MultipleSelectList's data the item so I get the list of exercise's id as the value. This is my first time using this library so I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

Comment: I got what the problem is. Instead of sending the `handleSelect` as a prop for `setSelected`, you have to send a stage-changing function. For example, take a new state using `const [selectedValues, setSelectedValue] = useState();` and add this a prop like `<MultipleSelectList setSelected={setSelectedValue}/>`. It would only work like this. Otherwise you would get the issue like you are getting now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with your data but with the setSelected prop for which you are sending a custom function `handleSelect`. But if you see the library's documentation, it is clearly mentioned like `setSelected is for For Setting the option value which will be stored in your local state`. So you can only store the selected values in the local state. The code should be like below inside the component.

```
const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState();

return <MultipleSelectList
    data={SOME_DATA}
    save="value"
    setSelected={setSelectedValues}
  />
```

Comment: but this way I cannot save selectedValues in the AsyncStorage, can I?

Comment: Please explore the `onSelect` prop as well on the MultipleSelectList list. When some value is selected, both the  `setSelected` and `onSelect` should get fired. The onSelect function is where you can pass the custom function and inside access the `selectedValues` to store inside async storage. Like below

`const onSelect = useCallback(() => {
 // Add the logic to store the AsyncStorage.
}, [selectedValues])`

`return <MultipleSelectList
    data={SOME_DATA}
    save="value"
    setSelected={setSelectedValues}
    onSelect={onSelect}
  />`

Comment: @AnnaTheBanana., As the issue main issue is resolved and the remaining is question is like an extra one, could you accept my answer?